# What does >| do in bash?

Tags: bash

In this article, [How To Create a Patch File for a RPM](http://wiki.networksecuritytoolkit.org/nstwiki/index.php/HowTo_Create_A_Patch_File_For_A_RPM), there is this command:

```
diff -ru base-1.4.4-orig base-1.4.4 >| $HOME/rpmbuild/SOURCES/base-1.4.4-f12.patch
```

Since the output is written to a file, the simple redirection operator `>` works fine for me.

Does this operator mean redirect to a pipe?  If so, how is a redirect to a pipe different from just a redirect to a file or just a pipe to a process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By executing the command

```
set -o noclobber
```

or the equivalent

```
set -C
```

you can cause bash to refuse to write to existing files when redirecting output.

Using `>|` rather than `>` overrides that setting.

References:

- [The `set` builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)
- [Redirecting Output](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirecting-Output)

Or run `info bash` (assuming it's installed on your system) and search for `>|`:

```
s>\|
```

(If you're familiar with csh and/or tcsh, bash's `>|` (greater-than vertical-bar) is similar to csh's `>!` (greater-than exclamation-mark).

Answer (score 2):

From the bash manpage:

> If the redirection operator  is  >|,  or  the  redirection
>   operator  is  > and the noclobber option to the set builtin command is not enabled, the redirection > is attempted even if the file named
>   by word exists.